# $P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET} sometimes/always(?) cannot be called twice within an expression

Tags: jasper-reports

I wanted to include a subreport which is fine as long as one does not reference/call the scriptlet via the `$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}` multiple times:

```
<subreport>
  ...
  <subreportExpression>
     /* "/myrep.jrxml" */                       /* runs fine */

     /* $P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.getMyRepPath() */  /* returns the above and runs fine */

     /* the report runs to the fill phase and may or may not (both experienced) 
      * after some time return and say, e.g. that the file has not been found 
      */
     $P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.dbg( "subreport: ", $P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.getMyRepPath() )
  </subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

It is based on the [*Jasper Utils* `EnvScriptlet`](https://bitbucket.org/andi1234/jasper-utils) in case it gives a clue about the cause.

Comment: Nice r&d. +1. Did you try to debug (what is a reason of such behavior)?

Comment: @Alex K: Thx. Sorry, I honestly have no time at the moment to debug it since the workaround below is ok for now :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**calling the static method directly** in the 2nd invocation like this however **works fine**:

```
<subreport>
  ...
  <subreportExpression>
     $P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.dbg( "subreport: ", EnvScriptlet.getMyRepPath() )
  </subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```